# Cast FsSql Count Result to Int32 without a Compiler Warning

Tags: f#, fssql

So I'm trying to do a simple count query in FsSql

```
 let! countOption = Sql.asyncExecScalar connectionManager (sprintf "select count(*) from %s" tableName) []
 match countOption with
 | Some count -> return dbCountToInt32 count
 | None _ -> return 0
```

The result of `asyncExecScalar` is `val countOption : obj option`

in my `dbCountToInt32` function I have tried the below methods to convert this into an int32.

```
        let dbCountToInt32 i64 =
            try
                // this throws a conversion exception `Can't cast Int64 to Int32`
                // int32(int64(i64)) 

                // this throws invalid cast exception `Can't cast Int64 to Int32`
                // int32(i64)

                //Works but throws a compiler warning `The type 'int64' does not have any proper subtypes and need not be used as the target of a static coercion`               
                int32(i64 :> int64)
            with 
            | _ -> 0
```

Unfortunately as you can see, two of the methods produce an exception and one works fine but has a compiler warning. Is there a way to make it work without a warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you're using the checked-cast operator `:>`, which has the compiler verify that your cast is valid. In this case, since you know the data in your `obj` is an `int64`, you can tell the compiler that you know better by using the unsafe-cast operator `:?>`.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want to do if/when there is an overflow

```
open System
let convertToIn32 (i:int64) : int32 = 
    let max32as64 = Convert.ToInt64(Int32.MaxValue)
    if(i > max32as64) then Int32.MaxValue else Convert.ToInt32(i)

printfn "%A" (10L |> convertToIn32)
printfn "converted 64 max is %A and int32 max is %A" (Int64.MaxValue |> convertToIn32) Int32.MaxValue
```

This will give you the max32 instead of throwing. Usually that is not what you want. There are possibly better and faster ways to handle this but this is clear and compared to a DB query a few conversions are probably ok.

Comment: I appreciate the answer. I REALLY hope we never hit a max int32 overflow on a row count lmao. It's possible. I really hope it doesn't happen though

Comment: @AnthonyRussell usually it is the next guy. Problem is you could always be the next guy on the next system :)

Comment: <kicks can down road> <lights match and tosses over shoulder>